# Can I use Timber Logger on my java library?

Tags: android, logging, timber-android

I add the Timber dependency to my Java Core Library Module build.gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.6.0'
```

Although it did not give an error when gradle synchronizes, I cannot see or use Timber class in the Core Library.

Comment: Hello. Did you find an alternative?

Comment: @Michael not, I gave up using timber in the java library

Comment: @Michael see my comment below

Answer (score 6):

<strike>Timber has a dependency on android.util.Log so it cannot be used in a pure Java module.</strike>

Decoupling the library from Android has been proposed but the creator of the library has decided against it. https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber/pull/63

The 5.0.0-SNAPSHOT version of Timber now supports usage in Java modules by using the `jdk` artifact.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.jakewharton.timber</groupId>
  <artifactId>timber-jdk</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: found any similar libs?

Comment: @BenjaminH No, the library module I where I ran into this issue was for an Android app so I converted it to be an Android library module instead of a Java module.  I haven't looked for a replacement.

Comment: That same issue you referenced now says there are two separate artifacts: `timber-jdk` and `timber-android`

Answer (score 5):

If anyone looking at Timber (Without android dependency) for mutli-module android project. Use `timber-jdk` like below.

In project's `build.gradle` file.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/' }
    }
}
```

In individual module `build.gradle` file (Example: Domain or remote module)

```
implementation "com.jakewharton.timber:timber-jdk:5.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

With this you should be able to implement `Timber` without android framework dependency

Answer (score 3):

If you have multi-module project, you can use Timber in pure Java/Kotlin with a tiny bit of abstraction involved, no external libraries.

Example with Kotlin and Koin:

**In pure kotlin module create a big imposter, Timber.kt:**

```
interface ILogger {
    fun d(message: String)
    fun e(message: String)
    fun e(throwable: Throwable, message: String)
    fun i(message: String)
}

object Timber: ILogger, KoinComponent {

    private val logger: ILogger by inject()

    override fun d(message: String) = logger.d(message)
    override fun e(message: String) = logger.e(message)
    override fun e(throwable: Throwable, message: String) = logger.e(throwable, message)
    override fun i(message: String) = logger.i(message)
}
```

**In app module create TimberLogger.kt:**

```
import timber.log.Timber

class TimberLogger : ILogger {

    override fun d(message: String) = Timber.d(message) // this is real timber this time
    override fun e(message: String) = Timber.e(message)
    override fun e(throwable: Throwable, message: String) = Timber.e(throwable, message)
    override fun i(message: String) = Timber.i(message)
}
```

**In app module, inject TimberLogger implementation into your fake Timber:**

```
val appModule = module {

    single<ILogger> { TimberLogger() }
}
```

Now you can simply call Timber.d("message") statically from anywhere.

If you have 2+ pure modules to use Timber in, consider creating Utils module and include it in rest of them, so it's available everywhere.

Comment: A little more functionality, and you don't need Timber at all

Comment: This works well, except it stops the automatic tag inference algorithm in `DebugTree` from working. The automatic tag now is "TimberLogger" because `DebugTree` inspects the call stack, which is altered if `Timber` calls are wrapped.

Comment: @PeterF you need to fetch correct tag from stacktrace. You can do this by extending DebugTree like here: https://github.com/chrisbanes/tivi/blob/main/base-android/src/main/java/app/tivi/util/TiviLogger.kt

Answer (score 1):

Try Arbor: Timber like logging implementation for Kotlin Multiplatform.

https://github.com/ToxicBakery/Arbor